# Dimension of the span of 3 linearly dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

$$u_1=(1,2,3)$$
$$u_2=(2,3,4)$$
$$u_3=(3,4,5)$$
I have shown $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ are linearly dependent, But I need to find the dimension of the span of $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$?

Comment: Dimension is three obv.by definition of dimension of a vector space.

Comment: You have a three dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. You might know this subspace already... :)

Comment: But the vectors _aren't_ linearly independent so they subspace isn't three-dimensional...

Comment: @Stack the question was edited

Comment: @marshalcraft Thanks; I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have shown $u_1$, $u_2$ and $u_3$ are linearly dependent, But I need to find the dimension of the span of $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$?

Since, as you say, the three vectors are linearly dependent, the dimension of the linear space spanned by $\vec u_1$, $\vec u_2$ and $\vec u_3$ can be at most 2. Clearly $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,3,4)$ are linearly independent because they aren't scalar multiples; so the dimension of the spanned space is 2.

---

You can still write:
$$\mbox{span} \left\{\vec u_1,\vec u_2,\vec u_3 \right\} = \left\{ x_1\vec u_1+x_2\vec u_2+x_3\vec u_3 \;\vert\; x_1, x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$but since $\vec u_3$ is a linear combination of $\vec u_1$, $\vec u_2$ (see above), it is also:
$$\mbox{span} \left\{\vec u_1,\vec u_2,\vec u_3 \right\} = \mbox{span} \left\{\vec u_1,\vec u_2 \right\} = \left\{ x_1\vec u_1+x_2\vec u_2 \;\vert\; x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
Based on a previous comment, you may want to write this in terms of the coordinates more explicitly:
$$\mbox{span} \left\{\vec u_1,\vec u_2 \right\} = \left\{ x_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}+x_2 \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} \;\vert\; x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \right\}= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x_1+2x_2 \\ 2x_1+3x_2 \\ 3x_1+4x_2 \end{pmatrix} \;\vert\; x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
Note that geometrically, this is a plane through the origin and containing the points $\vec u_1$ and $\vec u_2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ vectors are linearly independent then their span is $n$-dimensional.
The actual set spanned by them is $x_1u_1+x_2u_2+x_3u_3$, substituting your vectors in the place of $u_1,u_2,u_3$, we  get the span  as  $$(x_1+2x_2+3x_3,\ 2x_1+3x_2+4x_3,\ 3x_1+4x_2+5x_3) $$ for all possible scalars $x_i$.